# Android Fragment , ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments

> I want to add an icon in the action bar of a fragment. I
>   want that this icon could be shown only for one fragment but not for
>   the other fragments. i wrote in the fragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_carte_fragment, container, false);

              actionbar=getActivity().getActionBar();
              LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                layout.setLayoutParams(new  LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                layout.setGravity(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                ImageView add=new ImageView(getActivity());
                add.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
                layout.addView(add);
                actionbar.setCustomView(layout);
```

> But nothing is shown!

Comment: If what you want is an icon on the actionbar, why don't you do it with menu's? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Comment: Yes i tried it with "menu" but ,in this case the icon will be shown for all other fragments instead of only one. I need that the icon will be shown only for one fragment but not the other fragments

Comment: You can remove menu item for other fragments using menu.removeItem(R.id.menu_id);

Comment: are you using support action bar from v4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem few moths ago and I solved it with :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //Here you can inflate the icons that you want...
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{   

//You can add here the function that you want when click your icon
   switch (item.getItemId()) 
   {
     case R.id.search:  // it is going to refer the search id name in main.xml

     //add your code here

        return true;
     default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

Add this on your Fragment where you want to put the icon, don't forget the `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in your `onCreate`.

By the way, instead of add the icon grammatically just add it on your /res/menu

Comment: I think that your code can be added in the MainActivity and not in the fragment

Comment: I TRIED something like this, but the icon is always shown for all other fragments! I need it to be shown for **only one fragment!**

Comment: @mimi **NO!** If you want to add **differents icons** for each **fragment** you have to do by this way, if you want to add icons for **ALL** of your `Fragments` **YES**, you should add this on your `MainActivity`

Comment: You can hide you icon in onDestroy method of your IconShowFragment ) and show it again in onCreateView method .

Comment: @mimi You need to call setHasOptionsMenu(false); for other fragments

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    }
```

is it like this or like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //Here you can inflate the icons that you want...
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: is the second one, by the way, use edit button to post this since this is not an answer :)

Comment: when i put the second one I have an error : **remove @override annotation**

Comment: still an erro with "getMenuInflater()" But i think that i shouldn't remove it

Comment: Post your full Activity

Comment: @skizo Thank you..It works But with 
`@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    } `

Comment: No need remove, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Make actionbar menu that include your icon. And in your `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, you can use:

```
menuitemIcon.setVisible(true);
menuitemIcon.setVisible(false);
```

switch on/off the icon display.

To invoke actionbar menu refresh by:

```
invalidOptionsMenuHelper();
```

which will call `onPrepareOptionsMenu` to refresh menu.

Hope this help!